# Proper way of calling this LINK

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink

[PICTURE of Remove link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKDwP.jpg)

Proper way of calling the "Remove" link?

Using jquery, how can i possible call the function when i click the link "Remove" ?

inside the bootstrap modal

MY HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td valign="">
        <div id="imgtag"> 
            <center><div id="uploads3"><?php echo $eq_picPa; ?></div></center>
            <div id="tagbox">
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <div id="taglist"> 
            <span class="tagtitle">List of Tags</span> 
            <ol>
                <li rel="1"><a>jelly</a> (<a class="remove">Remove</a>)</li> 
            </ol> 
        </div> 
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

MY JS:

```
    $('#taglist').on('click', 'li a.remove',function(){
    alert('hi');
      id = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
      type = "remove";
      // get all tag on page load
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "savetag.php", 
        data: {"id": id, "type": type},
        success: function(data){
          viewtag();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: somebody help me please!

Comment: What is the response/error you are getting?

Comment: nothing. not triggering

Comment: my click function is that correct?

Comment: Did you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
$(document).on('click', '#taglist li a.remove',function(){
    alert('hi');
    //Your logic here....
});
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gokulmaha/phfs6bma/1/)

Comment: yeah it works like a charm :) sorry for late response

Comment: Keep rocking :-)